# In a group check box is it possible to select an option by clicking anywhere in the screen and not exactly inside the check box?

Tags: testing

From a group check box is it possible to select only one option. And I want to know whether a particular option can be selected without exactly clicking inside the check box. i,e Is it possible to select an option by just clickig somewhere in the screen where the text of the option is displayed.

I was testing an application and i found that it was able to select an option even without clicking inside the check box, so wanted to know whether that is a validation bug!!

Comment: *From a group check box it should be possible to select only one option*: then they should be radio buttons, not checkbox. Clicking on their label works fine.

Comment: If you have a set of options and only one of them should be selected, wouldn't a set of radio buttons be the answer?

Comment: I was testing an application and i found that it was able to select an option even without clicking inside the check box, so wanted to know whether that is a validation bug!!

Comment: It's expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that it is a bug if there is only one radio button or check box on the screen. Such type of functionality is sometimes provided in order to provide extra functionality to the user. There are certain validations that are capable to do this. But if there are multiple check boxes or radio buttons on the screen then it must be a bug. Because in case of multiple check boxes on the screen the script does not know which button to check.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comments.